# Java smslib and Android jelly bean 4.1.2

Tags: java, gsm, smslib

I have created an SMS project that sends SMSs via a GSM modem.  I used my phone (Samsung Galaxy S2) as the modem.

I was able to send SMSs from my phone when it was running Android version 4.0.4, and my application also worked with a Nokia phone.

However, since I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy to Android 4.1.2, I can't send SMSs any more.  Does anyone else get this problem with Android 4.1.2?

I know it is not my code because I have a C# SMS library from another source, and get the same result.

Here is my stack trace:

```
org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver$CharQueue.get(AModemDriver.java:535)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:338)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:313)
    at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler.getSimStatus(ATHandler.java:145)
    at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:132)
    at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
    at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

Comment: Windows? If it thought the device was new, then it would have allocated a different serial port number. Use the CommTest utility to test the port as well.